# Automatic VBA Time Stamp when Copying and pasting

Tags: excel, vba

Im new to VBA and was wondering if anyone can help me.

i have created this code which automatically adds a timestamp to a specific row when a cell is edited. However, if i want to paste in a load of data into the sheet, only the first row gets the timestamp, instead of every row.

can anyone help me?

thank you

Below is the current code used;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim MyTableRange As Range
Dim myUpdatedRange As Range

Set MyTableRange = Range("A2:J150")

If Intersect(Target, MyTableRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set myUpdatedRange = Range("K" & Target.Row)

myUpdatedRange.Value = Now()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Target` contains *all* cells that where modified. Simply loop over all cells in target will give you every single cell that was modified:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Target
   ...
Next
```

As you want to put only one timestamp per row, you can limit the loop to all cells of the first column of Target:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Target.Columns(1).Cells
    Cells(cell.Row, "K") = Now
    ' or, if you prefer:
    ' Range("K" & cell.Row) = Now
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: A Simple Time Stamp

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Range("A2:J150")
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(srg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Intersect(irg.EntireRow, Columns("K"))
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    drg.Value = Now
 
SafeExit:
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```