# Automatically update date and time data in column A when updating data in the range from B to Z

Tags: excel, vba, automatic-updates

Automatically update date and time data in column A when updating data in the range from B to Z.
Suppose I have a table of data located in the range B1:Z100, when I update the data in cell B1, the date and time in A1 will automatically update, and will automatically lock that data cell every time I press enter in case I accidentally pressed the wrong button. And when I update the data in cell B1, when I press Enter, it will display a message board whether I want to update new data to replace the old data. If agree, then press yes, and data cell B1 will be update the new data, and in cell A1 will update the date and time of the latest update at the same time.
Hope everyone can help me, thank you so much.

Comment: So you need to show examples of the data and what you have so far.

Comment: [This basic example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72060700) could be your starting point. Here's a list of [a few more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a9814069%20time%20stamp).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `Worksheet_Change` event.  This will fire every time a change is made to the worksheet.  In this sub, you can check for the row that was editted, and then you can ask the user the question about updating data.  [Here's the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)